# MySQLi prepared statements: insert increment of a value

Tags: php, mysqli, insert, prepared-statement

Is it possible in any way to **insert** an increment of a certain column value ?

```php
$stmt->$this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` ( `email`,`date_added`,`playCount`) VALUES ( ?, NOW(), ? )');

$stmt -> bind_param('si',$email, WHAT); // playCount++ somehow ...
$stmt -> execute();
```

I know I can use UPDATE to do that, but then I need to check if user exists first and then do INSERT and afterward UPDATE just for one column? There should be a better approach I think?

EDIT: UPDATE also won't work (won't prepare successfully-returns false: any ideas what might be wrong?)

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET `newsletter` = ?, `date_last` = NOW(),  points=points+?,  WHERE `email` = ?');
```

([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207153/how-can-i-increment-a-column-in-mysql-using-prepared-statements))

Comment: make the playcount column to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: This won't achieve what I want. It will only increase this value by one for each created user. What about when UPDATE is called? please see my edited question

Comment: Your query contains a syntax error. There's a comma before WHERE, so your update will fail. You can't do `++` style of adding info with INSERTS - it just makes no sense, you can't increment something that doesn't exist. This type of task is usually done by adding a unique constraint on a column, then you use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO users ( `email`,`date_added`,`playCount`) 
VALUES ( ?, NOW(), (SELECT MAX(playCount) from users)+1 );"
```